# sqlite-net-pcl {SQLite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios, sqlite-net

I´m currently developing an iOS App with Xamarin and ran into a strange error with sqlite-net-pcl:

```
{SQLite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error   at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (SQLitePCL.sqlite3 db, System.String query) [0x0001e] in <49ac49cfb94341128f6929b3ff2090ee>:0    at SQLite.PreparedSqlLiteInsertCommand.Prepare () [0x00011] in <49ac49cfb94341128f6929b…}
```

The error occours when I want to insert into a table of the following model:

```
public class PPPCount
{
    public PPPCount()
    {
    }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PerpePartCount { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the calling code:

```
try
{
    var con = await DbFactory.Instance();
    var perpetrationPartCount = await 
        service.GetSumPerpetrationParts(immobilePerpetrationId);

    var dbModel = await con.FindAsync<PPPCount>(immobilePerpetrationId);
    if (dbModel == null)
    {
        var model = new PPPCount();

        model.Id = immobilePerpetrationId;
        model.PerpePartCount = perpetrationPartCount;

        //This causes the exception!!!!
        await con.InsertAsync(perpetrationPartCount);
    }
    else
    {
        if (dbModel.PerpePartCount != perpetrationPartCount)
        {
            dbModel.PerpePartCount = perpetrationPartCount;
            await con.UpdateAsync(dbModel);
        }
    }
    return perpetrationPartCount;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //AlertHelper.ShowError(e.Message);
}
```

The code of the DbFactory that creates and holds my sqlite connection object:

```
public class DbFactory
{
    private static SQLiteAsyncConnection connection;

    public static async Task<SQLiteAsyncConnection> Instance()
    {
        if (connection == null)
        {
            bool deleteDb = false;
            string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "..", "immotech_offline.db3");

            if (File.Exists(dbPath) && deleteDb)
            {
                File.Delete(dbPath);
            }

            connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);

            try
            {

                await connection.CreateTableAsync<ImmobilePerpetration>();
                await connection.CreateTableAsync<Customer>();
                await connection.CreateTableAsync<PPPCount>();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //TODO: Delete this part!
                int i = 0;
            }
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

The strange thing is I can work with the two other models without any problems!
I really can´t explain what is causing this error and I tried to enable the tracing to show the SQL-Statements, but unfortunatelly the Async version of the sqlite connection object doesn´t provide a tracing.

Then I tried the same code in synchronous version with tracing enabled and this is the result:

```
insert  into "Int32"() values ()
```

Well this is very clear why it isn´t working, but how can such a statement be generated? Did I missed something or it is a bug?

UPDATE: Yes I used the search function and no case fits for my problem.

Comment: What type is returned by `service.GetSumPerpetrationParts(immobilePerpetrationId);`? Because that is what you are inserting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should this:

```
await con.InsertAsync(perpetrationPartCount);
```

be:

```
await con.InsertAsync(model);
```

We can't tell what type `perpetrationPartCount` is based on your code. It might not be a `PPPCount` and therefore that entity might not be the issue.

Comment: Oh my god, I can´t believe that I tried to insert just an integer value into my database! Thank you very much!

Comment: @valdetero I had the same issue. I changed to the above code and the error is gone but it is not inserting the record to the table.

Comment: @Rauf this issue is 5 years old. You should make a new issue with your code snippet for help.